# Using results from my own pass(not predefined pass) into next pass

Tags: llvm

I have created a pass that pathprofiles and then stores results in different data structures such as blocks corresponding to the paths, edges in paths etc.
 I have different variables and data structures for each of these.

Is there a way to use these variables directly in another pass that i write?
If yes, how? (Im not sure if getAnalysisUsage works for this?)
Urgent help required

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be late, but I had the same question, ran across your post and thanks to [Oak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242762/oak) was pointed into the right direction. So I wanted to share some code here.

Suppose you have two passes, the first one is your `PathProfilePass` and the second one is your `DoSomethingPass`. The first pass contains the data that you collect and share with the second path; nothing special needs to be done here:

```
/// Path profiling to gather heaps of data.
class PathProfilePass: public llvm::ModulePass {

  public:

    virtual bool runOnModule(llvm::Module &M) {

        // Create goodness for edges and paths.
        ...
    }

    std::set<Edges> edges;   ///< All the edges this pass collects.
    std::set<Paths> paths;   ///< All the paths this pass collects.
};
```

The interesting stuff happens in the second pass.  Two things you need to do here:

1. Specify the dependency of the second pass on the first pass: see the [getAnalysisUsage](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-getanalysisusage-method) method.
2. Access the data from the first pass: see the [getAnalysis](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-getanalysis-and-getanalysisifavailable-methods) method.

Code-wise it would look something like this for the second pass:

```
/// Doing something with edge and path informations.
class DoSomethingPass: public llvm::ModulePass {

  public:

    /// Specify the dependency of this pass on PathProfilePass.
    virtual void getAnalysisUsage(llvm::AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
        AU.addRequired<PathProfilePass>();
    }

    /// Use the data of the PathProfilePass.
    virtual bool runOnModule(llvm::Module &M) {

        PathProfilePass &PPP = getAnalysis<PathProfilePass>();

        // Get the edges and paths from the first pass.
        std::set<Edges> &edges = PPP.edges;
        std::set<Paths> &paths = PPP.paths;

        // Now you can noodle over that data.
        ...
    }
};
```

*Disclaimer:* I haven't compiled this code, but this is an adaptation to your example of what works for me. Hope this is useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Set a dependency from the 2nd pass to the 1st pass (via overriding `getAnalysisUsage` and invoking `getAnalysis` - see [the programmer's guide to writing a pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#specifying-interactions-between-passes) on how to do that). Once you get an instance of the 1st pass, you can use it just like any other C++ object.

Comment: when i put the pass name of the 1st pass in getAnalsisUsage using virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {AU.addRequired<blockPath>();} where blockPath is the name of my 1st pass , during make im getting the error as "unknown type name  blockPath"

Comment: @user2237704 that sounds like a standard C++ symbol lookup error, have you verified the type name is correct and that it's in scope (e.g. maybe it's in a different namespace, so you need something like `my_namespace::BlockPath` and not `blockPath`)? Have you verified you have the proper `#include`s?